# Redesigning the list view

Tags: list, magento, view, product

Hi i am busy setting up the product page, but there is one problem.
i am going to sell allot of same products with just the length is different.

Nou i have a theme for my magento website, "ultimo"

there is the Grid an list view,
now i want to use the list view as a standard , but the size is just to big, so i want the size of a product to be smaller , or lower.

image 1:[enter link description here](http://www.datbouwikzelf.nl/media/wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/custom/test/productnow.jpg)

but this is just to high, to place 50 product on one page, i have seen this on many site
and i was wondering if this is possible so i made a example to show what is want.

image 2: [enter link description here](http://www.datbouwikzelf.nl/media/wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/custom/test/productnow2.jpg)

I have been looking , in Phtml fils, Css, Xml but can't find noting to make a new list 
so i am looking for someone , who can show me how this is done, i don't have that much of experience in HTML , CSS of PHP for that matter. so if someone knows how to do this that would be great.

but the first thing i would like to know is this possible

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You have to customize following files:

1. app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
2. skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/styles.css

And you can use ajax cart extension for your project.

Comment: after searching all day yesterday , i found out that it also uses a grid12.css file to rule some sizes. i managed to change it and remove some elements that i don't want to use. but still i need to edit it further. it looks like it has been separated into 3 sections. image - product description - order.

Comment: grid12.css is one for responsive. are you new on magento? If yes, I can do your project for you.

Comment: That would be great, could i contact you via email james ?

Comment: hi, is it even possible to send a personal message ? i cannot see your email in your profile.

Comment: I don't know how to make my email address as public.

Comment: if you would like to contact me via this email - jeromevet@zeelandnet.nl after we have had contact i remove this comment.